# Coutinuous distribution in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If suppose there is an **interval** $[a,b]$ then choosing **a number** from it is **equal probable** and a number can be any **real number** within the interval. Is it a case of **continuous distribution** ? How to calculate the **probability** of choosing a number?

Comment: It is continuous and thus there isn't a probability of a _single_ number--only ranges of numbers (and small ranges will result in small probabilities since it's uniform).

Comment: if there is an interval `[3,5]` choosing a number is equal probable then what is the probability of the interval `[4.3,4.7]` and how to calculate it?

Comment: Intuitively it's very simple: $4.7 - 4.3 = 0.4$ and the total length of the interval is $2.0$ thus if all values are equally likely, then it's simply $\frac{0.4}{2.0} = 0.2 = 20\%$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the concept of a uniform distribution over the interval $[a,b]$, but it's not as simple as "choosing each number with equal probability." You can't have a uniform probability distribution over an infinite set that assigns positive probability to a single point. To see this, suppose $\mathbb P(\{x\})=c>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then
$$\sum_{x\in[a,b]}\mathbb P(\{x\})=\infty, $$
which of course is impossible for a probability measure (as we must have $\mathbb P([a,b])=1$). Instead, we consider a probability measure that assigns to each subinterval $[x,y]$ of $[a,b]$ (that is, $a\leqslant x \leqslant y \leqslant b$) the probability
$$ \mathbb P([x,y]) = \frac{y-x}{b-a}.$$
So if $x=y$ then $[x,y]=\{x\}$ and $\mathbb P(\{x\})=0$. If $a=x$ and $y=b$ then $\mathbb P([x,y])=\mathbb P([a,b])$. If $x>a$ or $y<b$ then $\mathbb P([x,y])$ is strictly between $0$ and $1$.

To get an intuition of this, graph the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac1{b-a},& a\leqslant x \leqslant b\\ 0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Then the probability of choosing a number in the interval $[x,y]$ is the area under the curve of $f$ from $x$ to $y$, i.e.

$$\mathbb P([x,y])=\int_x^y\frac1{b-a}\mathsf dt = \frac{y-x}{b-a}.$$

Of course, integration is not necessary here; it's clear that the region is a rectangle with height $\frac1{b-a}$ and width $y-x$, so the area is $$(y-x)\left(\frac1{b-a}\right)=\frac{y-x}{b-a}.$$